# Setting height and width for '@Html.TextBoxFor' issue

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

I have tried searching for the correct way to change height and width a `@Html.TextBoxFor` element, but I could not find a good solution. The way I have the razor frontend setup, the text box puts the input text in the middle. How could I fix this issue, would I have to use normal html instead or what could I do? [image]

The razor code is here:

```
@model GuildCars.UI.Models.CarEditViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Vehicle";
}


<style>
    .col-25 {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        padding-right: 16px;
    }

    .largeTextBox {
        height: 140px;
        min-width: 400px;
        width:400px;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6">
        <h2>Edit Vehicle</h2>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "frmAddVehicle" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
            ...
            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-25">
                    <label>Mileage</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mileage, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-25">
                    <label>VIN</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VIN, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-25">
                    <label>MSRP</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MSRP, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-25">
                    <label>Mileage</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mileage, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control largeTextBox" })
                </div>
                </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `@Html.TextAreaFor` like this

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control largeTextBox" })
```